# "Work in a power plant", "work on a power plant" or "work at a power plant"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do I use if I want to say that someone's work place is a power plant? For example:

> I work **in** a power plant.
>
> I work **on** a power plant.
>
> I work **at** a power plant.

Comment: _I'm Working On a Building_

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a great question!

The first and third options - "**in** a power plant" and "**at** a power plant" - are both correct for **this specific example** of work, so long as you mean "doing some job inside an existing power plant".

The second option "**on** the power plant" would mean something different - e.g. that you are an engineer or labourer involved with the construction of a new power plant. For instance:

> "I'm a design engineer, and I am working on the power plant == "I am
>   working on the design of the power plant."

However, in other cases, the "on" preposition will be appropriate.  The **general principle** is that:

- "at" or "in" are generally used when the worksite is indoors (e.g. an office, factory, shop, etc), while
- "on" is typically used when the worksite is an outdoor structure (and the work is done largely outside).

The following examples illustrate.

**Examples where "in" or "at" are (largely) interchangeable**

- "I work in a bank." or "I work at the bank."
- "I work in a factory." or "I work at a factory."
- "I work in a grocery store." or "I work at the grocery store."
- "I work in a power plant." or "I work at a power plant."

Note that in these examples, the "at" preposition will generally be more appropriate where the workplace is a specific workplace (preceded by "the").

**Examples where "on" is essential**

- "I work on an oil rig."
- "I work on a ship."
- "I work on the rail tracks."

**Examples where "on" or "at" are largely interchangeable**

- "I work on a construction site." or "I work at a construction site."
- "I work on the wharves." or "I work at the wharves."

**Examples where "at" is essential**

- "I work at the outdoor vegetable markets."

Comment: I think "I work **in** the outdoor vegetable markets." wouldn't sound too unnatural, despite "at" being favourable. But I would add that "at" would be the only appropriate preposition if the worksite isn't a physical place, e.g., "I work at Amazon". But in that case, you could use "for".

Comment: @Jam - That's a great point about "at"  being the right options where the worksite isn't  a physical place, and "for" being another option.  Reading your comment also reminded me that "with" is appropriate in some cases - e.g. "I work with Amazon" (suggesting that I'm a consultant rather than an employee). It just goes to show that we have many prepositional choices!

Comment: But 'work on a boat' can mean both simple location and involvement in its construction.   A sailor works on (not at or in) a boat.  A ship-builder works on a boat (at a boatyard).

Comment: @LaurencePayne - Great example!

Comment: Not sure your inside/outside works. 'I work in the fields'

Comment: I think these rules are too specific. This is a decent first pass, but there’s just a few that don’t really fit. I guess as with all of English, it’s complicated.

Comment: @Aequitas - Great example!  But the interesting question is *why*?  Why is it "**in** a field" but "**on** a construction site" and "**at** the outdoor markets"?  My answer was an attempt to search out the underlying rules, but clearly the story is far more complex!

Comment: @Tim - I agree 100% that it's far more complicated!  :)  I began answering what I thought was a pretty easy question, but it became more complex as I wrote.  In the end I just pressed the "post" button, intending it to be no more than a reasonable first pass.  The interesting thing is that native speakers clearly know the rules intuitively ... but why?  Is there some underlying algorithm that specifies the rules?  Or is just convention?  I'm keenly interested to hear answers from others!

Comment: @TechnoCat I think you’ve got the general answer and then it’s a combo of what “sounds” natural and learning from hearing others say it. I certainly couldn’t tell you the rules I use, it’s just “natural”!

Comment: "Note that in these examples, the "at" preposition will generally be more appropriate where the workplace is a specific workplace (preceded by "the")." I don't think this is right.  "At the bank" sounds like there is only one.  "At a bank" is certainly better.  The user of "a" vs "the" is confusing enough as it is; I think you should take this out and replace your "the"'s with "a"'s.  I speculate that people used to say "at the bank" or "at the grocery store" when there was only one of those in a town, and it may have carried over as an idiom.

Comment: I disagree with "I work at the outdoor vegetable markets." - this sounds wrong to me, particularly if you reduce it to the bare bones: "I work at the markets." would always be either "I work at the market." (singular) or "I work in the markets." if the plural is valid.

Answer (score 24):

All three could be used, but they have slightly different connotations concerning the exact workplace of the worker.

> I work **in** a power plant.

The employee's tasks are inside the power plant. (She may be a janitor, but her work is inside the structure.)

> I work **on** a power plant.

The worker's job is constructing or caring for the power plant itself. (He is probably a civil, electrical, or mechanical engineer.)

> I work **at** a power plant.

The laborer's work is located within the property lines of the premises of the power plant. (She may be outdoor security or landscaper or driver and she never enters the power plant, even though she works near it.)

Additionally, one also might say:

> I work **for** a power plant.

The worker's employer is a company that owns the power plant. (He may be a worker from the previous examples or he may be a researcher or manager or salesman who does all his work off-site.)

Comment: "On a power plant" sounds odd unless you are either constructing it... or a different kind of power plant (a jet engine) is meant...

Comment: @Jed_Schaaf - These are good points!

Comment: This is a good answer for the subtle difference, even in this context, between ‘in’ and ‘at’.

Comment: Hmm. I would take issue with the last one. Power plants are equipment owned by utility companies, so the plant isn't the employer. And "at" sounds better to me than "in," but that might be regional. Signed, someone who used to work for a utility company (but not at a power plant).

Comment: For the specific instance of power plant, you'd be correct Elizabeth, but conceivably if a power plant was self-run (however unusual) e.g. by Mr Burns of Simpsons fame, it would be correct.

Comment: The in/at distinction is correct but not really followed to the letter by most speakers. The distinction mostly doesn't matter here since the intention of the message is to convey employment rather than precise location.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning - That's a good  point.  Your examples highlight that "for" signifies a contractual (or employer/employee, master/servant) relationship, whereas "at" is just locational.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I'm not sure I understand your issue. It sounds to me like you said exactly the same thing I did: that the power plant is owned by the employing company. In particular, people may be more familiar with the power plant, but not its owner (or maybe the owner has changed frequently, so the speaker or their audience may not know who the current owner is), so they'll just say they work "for the power plant" instead of "for XYZ Utilities." It's one fairly common usage of synecdoche/metonymy.